# Volatile Object working

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

Consider below scenario, it says if `str` is volatile it means any update by any thread accessing `str`, will directly update on main stack instead of local Thread cache.

```
class A{
  volatile String str;     
  volatile B b=new B();
}

class B{
  int a;
  C c;
}
```

For `b` volatile object, how scenario will work?

I read few links it says only reference is volatile and not the property of object itself, what does that mean, can some one help me with some example as I am finding it little bit difficult to understand.

if reference is synchronized, then how it will help, what is the use of it?

Answer (score 1):

First scenario:

- thread 1 does `a.b = new B();`
- then thread 2 does `B b = a.b;`

In this case, you have the guarantee that the object referenced by `b` in the second thread is the `new B()` that the first thread has assigned to the variable.

Second scenario:

- thread 1 does `a.b.setFoo("hello");`
- then thread 2 does `String s = a.b.getFoo();`

In this case, you have no guarantee regarding the value of `s` in the second thread. It could be "hello", or it could be a previous value of `a.b.foo` (unless the `foo` attribute in class B is itself volatile, or the setters and getters are synchronized).

Comment: Can `thread 2` read the latest value of `foo` if `thread 1` reassigns the `b` ref ? e.g. `thread 1`: `{ a.b.setFoo("Hello"); a.b = a.b; }` then `thread 2`: `{ a.b.getFoo(); }`

Comment: Comments to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4614433/1812434) discuss the same point but not clear (to me :) )