# Volatile reference and subsequently setting the value of the variable

Tags: java

Consider the snippet:

```
class Mutable {
    private volatile int value;
    public int get()
    {
        return value;
    }
    public int set(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

class Test {
    public volatile Mutable m;
}
```

So using the following sequence:

```
Thread-1: get()     // returns 2
Thread-2: set(3)
Thread-1: get()     // guaranteed to return 3 due to volatile with property value
```

But I am unable to understand the following note by the author-

> one note however, when m is assigned, the internal value will be
>   correctly visible. **it is only after subsequent calls to set() which do
>   not write m that you have problems**.

Please exemplify. Which problem is he talking about?

Comment: volatile keyword means that value will be guaranteed to be update for any thread access.

Comment: @Reza: I am not asking what volatile is. But how will subsequently calling set() will result in inconsistency b/w threads.

Comment: Are you asking for another person's code/problem?

Comment: What is `m`? Can you give the actual code this author is talking about, or link to it?

Comment: @qxz: assume - public volatile Mutable m = new Mutable();

Comment: Whoops, sorry, didn't notice that in the second class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the reason that last comment is confusing, is because it got taken out of context.  The example code you provided is *different* from the [original code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614331/using-volatile-keyword-with-mutable-object/) to which that comment was directed.  in the *original* code, `value` was *not* volatile.  When `value` is not volatile, then you have the following situation.

Thread1:

```
Mutable tmp = new Mutable();
tmp.set(3);
Test.m = tmp;
```

Thread2:

```
Test.m.get();  // *** this is guaranteed to return 3 due to the happens before rules.
```

Thread1:

```
Test.m.set(5);
```

Thread2:

```
Test.m.get();  // no guaranatees here, could be 3, could be 5
```

My comment was referring to the "***" part, where the volatile assignment of `m` provides the happens before relationship which makes "3" visible to to Thread2 (due to the volatile read of `m`).  (to re-iterate, `value` is not volatile in this example).

Comment: Don't you think when value is not volatile, then the statements `1 - tmp.set(3);` & `2 - Test.m = tmp;` executed by the thread 1 could be re-ordered and at the same time if Thread 2 were to execute Test.m.get();, it might get the default value of instance variable value i.e 0. Or are you assuming that Thread 2 will be executing the code snippet much later after Thread 1 has executed.

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari - no.  that is one of the guarantees of volatile in the jdk 5+ memory model.  the memory model changes included non-volatile changes as part of the happens before relationship created by volatile.  that is why volatile has the same memory effects as synchronized in a jdk 5+ world.  in other words, the first non-volatile assignment (in `set(3)`) _cannot_ be re-ordered past the volatile assignment of `m`.

Comment: Impressive, I surmise you mean - When thread A writes to a volatile variable and subsequently thread B reads that same variable, the values of all variables that were visible to A prior to writing to the volatile variable become visible to B after reading the volatile variable. So from a memory visibility perspective, writing a volatile variable is like exiting a synchronized block and reading a volatile variable is like entering a synchronized block.

Comment: @ShirgillFarhanAnsari - that is pretty much exactly correct.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, the problematic part is that the `volatile` guarantees a happens-before relationship between read and write accesses. We just don't know what will happen with quick write operators:

```
Thread-1: get()     // returns 2

// no real happens-before on the 3 lines below:
Thread-2: set(3)
Thread-3: set(4)
Thread-4: set(5)

// now what?
Thread-1: get()     // guaranteed to return 3 or 4 or 5 due to volatile with property value
```

A more tricky case is the incrementing a counter:

```
Thread-1: get()     // returns 2

// no real happens-before on the 3 lines below. They all might increment the 2:
Thread-2: set(get()+1)
Thread-3: set(get()+1)
Thread-4: set(get()+1)

// now what?
Thread-1: get()     // guaranteed to return 3 or 4 or 5 due to volatile with property value
```

Comment: I would say that due to presence of `volatile` keyword on `value`, the first code snippet of your would definitely return `5` as volatile guarantees that. Second one I am unsure.

Comment: The point with the first snippet is that I had to write the threads in some order. The `jvm` doesn't have to do that. Those sets can occur parallelly.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for statements re-ordering.

Comment: This answer doesn't say much about the happens before relationship, it just points out the nondeterminate nature of parallelism and the fact that volatile members are not atomic.

Comment: @jtahlborn indeed. This answer provides some examples when there's no happens-before relationship. As far as I understood, this is what the OP asked. Also, this answer doesn't pretend to explain the happens-before relationship.